# Solve $x^2+y^2=2$ for $x,y\in\mathbb Q$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Solve $x^2+y^2=2$ for $x,y\in\mathbb Q$.

I think the answer should be in terms of 1 integer variable $\in\mathbb Z$ only. I rewrite the equation to $(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2=2^2$, then by the formula of pythagorean triples, $x+y=u^2-v^2,x-y=2uv,2=u^2+v^2$. How can I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Recall that $x=(x+y)+(x-y)/2$.

Comment: But then the answer will involve 2 variables...

Comment: But $u$ and $v$ is a solution to your original problem, and hence is of $1$ degree of freedom?

Comment: $u, v\in\Bbb{Z}$ or $u, v\in\Bbb{Q}$? (I really don't know--I'm trying to learn as much as I can by reading questions... :))

Comment: @awllower: But, for example, like solving $x^2+y^2=1$ for $x,y∈\mathbb Q $, the solution is $(x,y)=((1-t^2)/(1+t^2),2t/(1+t^2))$, $t\in\mathbb Z$ only 1 variable...

Comment: @anorton: $u,v\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: ARRR... I don't know ...

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ I ask, because if $u^2+v^2 = 2$ and $u, v\in\Bbb{Z}$, there are only $6$ [solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u^2+%2B+v^2+%3D+2+diophantine) for $u$ and $v$. Thus, you can back solve...

Comment: I think what many are trying to use here is some version of Pythagoras: Or, consider any Pythagorean triple (a,b,c) in $\mathbb Z^3$ ,with $gcd(a,c)$ and $gcd(b,c)$ both greater than 1, i.e., each of a,b,c is an integer satisfying:

  $a^2+b^2=c^2$ , then, the pair $(\frac{2a}{c},\frac{2b}{c})$ satisfies:

  $(\frac{2a}{c})^2+ (\frac{2b}{c})^2= \frac{4a^2+4b^2}{c^2}=\frac{4(a^2+b^2)}{c^2}=4=2^2)$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solutions to the equation $x^2+y^2=2$ with $x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$ can be parametrized by $$\left(x,y\right)=\left(\frac{1+2t-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}},\ \frac{1-2t-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right),$$ where $t\in \mathbb{Q}$.

This follows by rewriting the equation as $$\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^{2}=1,$$ and using the parametrization for $u^2+v^2=1$.   Consequently, we see that $$\left(\frac{x+y}{2},\ \frac{x-y}{2}\right)=\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}},\ \frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}\right),$$ and so we arrive at  $$\left(x,y\right)=\left(\frac{1+2t-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}},\ \frac{1-2t-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right).$$

Comment: I get it, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

We can imitate one standard method of finding a rational parametrization of the unit circle.

Note that the point $A=(1,1)$ is on our curve. Let $m$ be rational, and consider the line with slope $m$ passing through  $(1,1)$. This has equation $y=m(x-1)+1$.

Substituting in $x^2+y^2=2$, we get after a while the equation
$$x^2(m^2+1)-2(m^2-m)x+m^2-2m-1=0.$$
One of the roots of this equation is $x=1$. Since the product of the roots is $\frac{m^2-2m+1}{m^2+1}$, it follows that the other root is given by 
$$x=\frac{m^2-2m-1}{m^2+1}.$$
In particular, this root is rational. Conversely, if $P\ne A$ is (almost) any rational point on the curve, then the slope $m$ of the line $AP$ is rational. (The exception is $(1,-1)$, since then technicallly the slope does not exist.)

The value of $y$ corresponding to the above $x$ is 
$$y=-\frac{m^2+2m-1}{m^2+1}.$$
By stretching things a bit, we view the exceptional point  $(1,-1)$ as also being on the parametrized curve, if we allow "$m=\infty$."